# How to connect Oracle SQL to MS Access file?

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I do not have write-only access to many database and so cannot execute a lot of commands. However I would want to check a few write commands for SQL? So connecting an MS Access file(with data) to my SQL server would do great good. So please guide regarding this?

Comment: I do not understand at all what you are trying to do. - Please try to edit the question to be more clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://www.orafaq.com/node/60

It explains how to create a dblink from oracle to msaccess. (You tagged your question with Oracle even though you refer to SQL server in the text)